# jQuery/Javascript Cookies and variable returning with value [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am attempting to set a cookie to a site using jQuery, ONLY if the user came from a specific site. In this case, lets use -http://referrersite.com- as the site they must come from for the cookie to be created as an example. The cookie value is being stored in a variable and everything up to this point is working fine.

There is a conditional statement checking whether the user came from the referred site, if the cookie exists already and if the cookie doesn't exist and the user did not come from the referred site. If the user came from the referred site the cookie is created and stored in a variable. If the cookie already exists, it is then stored in a variable. If the cookie does not exist and the user did not come from the referred site I am assigning the variable a static string of characters - this is where the issue lies.

When the variable is alerted from the non referred site and no existing cookie, it returns: [object Object], not the static string of characters.

The code I am using is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var referrer = document.referrer;

    if(referrer == "http://referrersite.com") {

        $.cookie("code","123456", { expires: 90, path: '/' });
        cookieContainer = $.cookie("code");
        alert(cookieContainer);

    } else if($.cookie("code")) {

        cookieContainer = $.cookie("code");
        alert(cookieContainer);

    } else if($.cookie("code") == null && referrer != "http://referrersite.com") {

        cookieContainer = "67890";
        alert(cookieContainer);

    }

});
```

In conclusion, my goal is to set `cookieContainer` with the string `"67890"` if the user did not come from the referred site, and `$.cookie("code")` does not exist. For some reason it is containing an object instead.

Please let me know if there is something I am missing as the code to me looks like it should work.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `alert` and you can actually inspect what's in the object.  non-referred no existing seems like `cookieContainer` is just `"67890"` though.

Comment: Why is the last `else if` not just an `else`?

Comment: Explosion Pills (awesome name btw) - I will try that. The variable cookieContainer should only contain the string  `"67890"` if the user did not come from the referred site and if `$.cookie("code")` does not exist.

Comment: epascarello - I had the last `else if` as just `else` before. I am just trying every alternative and trying to corner every angle.

Answer (score 0):

`[Object Object]` In short means the data in the cookie isn't a string, well not exactly. Chances are the data in the cookie more so resembles that of a JSON string/object. And to alert it out, print it on screen, or whatever it is your trying to do in the long run your going to have to either do a loop over the object and have it print it all out.. or if you know which property you want specifically you will have to call it specifically.

eg:

```
if(cookieContainer.property_name_whatever)
{
    alert(cookieContainer.property_name_whatever);
}
```

To find out the individual properties I would say your easiest bet with javascript is using Firefox, install the `Firebug` http://getfirebug.com/, and in your code instead of `alert(cookieContainer)` do `console.log(cookieContainer)` . After enabling the console with firebug, this will read the object as a whole and display the data on a per property => value basis.

The reason something exists when its not the cookie your looking for is its likely the person on the site came from another site or search engine. In using `document.referrer` any url landing to your page even internals can and likely will be treated as a referrer, its ultimately dependant upon the browser itself though, as all the major ones support it, they all treat it differently in various degrees. Im not going to lay claim completely understanding that particular object as I dont use it often myself. But to quote W3

> Definition and Usage
>
> The referrer property returns the URL of the document that loaded the
>   current document.

The URL in mention could even be you on the same site jumping back and forth between pages via links on your page (Not sure if that applies on reloads/refreshes, but it could I suppose)

Comment: I will try using the console, for sure. The only thing is, if the user did not get to the landing page from the specific referrer site, and `$.cookie("code")` does not exist, cookieContainer should only contain the string `"67890"`. For some reason it contains an object even though I am not passing a cookie or object to the variable upon those conditions.

Thanks for your help BTW!